# Spring form tag- Speicfying commandname as a variable from c:forEach tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am having a set of results in array, i want to display them in a form using 
All results are of the same type (Classes in package beans in Java).

```
<c:forEach items="${resultBeans}" var="resultBean">
<form:form commandName="${resultBean}" action="getdata.htm">
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td>
                <td><form:input id="id" path="id"/></td>
                <td><form:input id="name" path="name"/></td>
            </form:form>
</c:foreach>
```

But i get the error saying 
**"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'beans' available as request attribute"**
How to specify commandname for such results?

Comment: does setting commandName to modelAttribute gives you same error?

Comment: The commandname will be based on each row in the array, so i cannot set it in controller beforehand.PLease let me know if this can be done.

Comment: Can you show us your controller?